# Bloch wave packets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, condensed-matter

I have been studying Condensed matter physics, and there are some basics that are confusing me. Basically, when we find the dispersion relations of electrons in a lattice using the nearly free electron model, I do not get what the dispersion relation signifies physically. If we have one electron per orbital, I know that the band will be half-filled, which means that we have electron waves with those particular k values, but then how is the concept of Bloch wave packets incorporated? In Yang and Grivin, when the Bloch envelope is introduced, they integrate Blochs function over all k values, from which I thought all these electron waves superpose to make a wave packet of some average momentum. But then going forward, when considering the dispersion relation I got confused that will we still be looking at electrons in particular states individually? When we consider Bragg reflection at the boundaries of the Brillouin zone, does it mean that electrons with that crystal momentum form standing waves, all the while the other electrons with the other k values continue to propagate, and they all superpose to form a resultant wave or is it like when the wave packets k value becomes the k value at the boundary, it forms a standing wave?

Answer (score 0):

*Bloch waves are eigenstates of an electron in the lattice potential, whereas the dispersion relation is the corresponding eigenenergy.* In other words, we are simply solving Schrödinger equation for an electron in a lattice.

*Atomic orbitals* are not eigenstates, since, when the atoms are close to each other, the electrons can hop from one orbital to another (in the same way the eigentsates of a hydrogen atom are not eigenstates of a hydrogen molecule.)

*Bloch wave packets* are combinations of the true eigenstates that are localized on a specific atom. They are not eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, but they are more convenient in some situations - like the position basis in one-particle quantum mechanical problems. Bloch packets are also orthogonal to each other, i.e., they form a basis (even though it is not the eigenbasis of the Hamiltonian) in which other wave functions can be expanded. Using atomic orbitals instead is just a crude approximation of Bloch packets, since it implies neglecting the hopping / modification of the atomic potential when the atoms are brought together - we simply use the solutions for isolated atoms.

**Suggestion**
Solving a one-dimensional tight-binding model is an extremely useful exercise, which can make much understanding go away (even though the problem implies an artificial decomposition of the potential in orbital energies and hopping integrals):
$$
H=\sum_{j=1}^N\epsilon_0|j\rangle\langle j|+t\sum_{j=1}^N\left(|j\rangle\langle j+1|+|j+1\rangle\langle j|\right).
$$
Here $|j\rangle$ is the orbital on the $j$-th atom, $\epsilon_0$ is the energy of this orbital, $t$ is the *hopping integral*. For simplicity one assumes periodic boundary conditions: $|j+N\rangle=|j\rangle$. Note that orbital states are not eigenstates of this Hamiltonian, because of the possibility of hopping.
The Schrödinger equation is $$H|\psi\rangle=E|\psi\rangle$$ is solved by Bloch states, i.e., via ansatz
$$|\psi_k\rangle\propto \sum_{j=1}^Ne^{ikj}|j\rangle,$$
which results in eigenenergies
$$E_k=-2t\cos(k).$$
One can now construct the Bloch packets and see that, although the significant contribution to each packet comes from the orbital on which it is centered, this is not the only contribution.

**Remark**
I mentioned earlier that the tight-binding problem is approximate. Indeed, by construction the orbitals of this model do form a complete basis, and solution is just a combination of these basis states. If we were to consider a real atomic potential, the orbitals of atoms would overlap, and thus would not form a basis - an assertion that I made earlier.

Comment: According to this, Bloch wave packets are formed from the Bloch states which solve the tight-binding model, so that again each state that is shown in a dispersion relation, their summation forms a packet. So what exactly is realized in the state physically? Is it the wave packet or is it the valence electrons of each atom? LatterI am thinking won't be the case, because we solve for a single electron in a periodic potential? But then in books band filling is described as just adding electrons to these states. I guess that's confusing me- what is physically realised.

Comment: @Meganmars Bloch packets are superpositions of Bloch waves and vice versa - it is equivalent of switching between momentum and position representation in QM without lattice. *Filing the band* can be done in many different ways. However, the discussions that you refer to are not of some physical process, but mental construction of a filled band from basic elements.